# unixODBC documentation / manpage?

Tags: man, documentation, database

Just wondering if there is any official documentation for unixODBC, e.g. how the configuration files have to look like and what parameters they expect? (I am using only a shell, no GUI) Even http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/ doesn't look very promising. I somehow have the impression, the best information are 3rd party pages, but can this be true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right the documentation about `unixODBC` still rare. For the configurations files, `unixODBC` use only two config files:

- `/etc/odbcinst.ini` : Here you define the driver
- `/etc/odbc.ini` : Informations about connections

You can find a great documentation about installing this drivers and libraries on various linux systems here:

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_configuring_odbc.html

More complete documentation that include API for various languages can be found here:

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html

All the config and installation stuff can be made without GUI :), an old good terminal shell suffice.

From a developer point a view (iused the C API few years ago, and i remember that it was a non trivial task): you need to connect and then perform a request.

1. To connect to the datasource using unixODBC and the `C API`:

   - Init ODBC environnement by calling `SQLAllocHandle()`
   - Choose ODBC version number with `SQLSetEnvAttr()`
   - Again use `SQLAllocHandle()` to init the connection handle
   - Now you can connect by calling `SQLConnect()`
2. Once you have a connection handle and have connected to a data source you allocate statement handles to execute SQL or retrieve meta data. As with the other handles you can set and get statement attributes with `SQLSetStmtAttr` and `SQLGetStmtAttr`.

here you can find a good documentation on the C API:

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html
http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc-tutorial-fetching-results.html
http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/diagnostics_error_status_codes.html

Comment: thank you very much TOC, I don't need it for programming, just for asterisk, where your link comes in handy, great :-)